# How to see only `Create View` column from SHOW CREATE VIEW?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to generate script to modify multiple views. I was wishing to runs multiple `SHOW CREATE VIEW` against these views and then modify output.

Unfortunately, I can't do anything with this command output. For example, I can't choose output columns, for example, only column of `Create View`, which contains create view syntax only. I have also `View`, `character_set_client` and `collation_connection` columns. How to choose not to display them?

Comment: I guess you have to pipe the output to another program that extracts what you want.

Comment: wow! thats incredible!

Comment: Try [23.30 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA VIEWS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views-table.html).

Comment: Maybe you could share the big picture to get more accurate answers. I mean, if you're already writing a custom script that's able to parse the `CREATE VIEW` SQL code (a fairly complex task), what prevents it from ignoring the other columns of `SHOW CREATE VIEW`?

Comment: @Dims -- Being from the east coast I appreciate your sarcasm -- I'll point out this was the best answer I could given *the incredibly useful and informative question you posted*.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: @Hogan my sarcasm was addressed to MySQL creators, not to you, sorry. What increadible mind it is required to have to create a database tool, which is both intended to select and choose data, but which is relied on 3rd party tools to select and choose in SOME cases...

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the known result and pipe it with awk, leaving only the second result column with the pure create statement. The columns are devided by single tabulator.

```
mysql -h<HOST> -u<MYSQLUSER> -p<PASSWORT> -N -B -e "SHOW CREATE VIEW <DATABASE>.<VIEW>;" | awk -F '\t' '{print $2}'
```